# Ubuntu Server scheduleing a cron job not working

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am trying to schedule a cronjob on my ubuntu server through SSL. I ran the command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then once it created a new file for my user, I put :

```
* * * * *  php /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/automation/cronjob_WDYCI_daily.php
```

at the bottom.

But it is not working... Anyone have an idea what it should be?

Comment: I've never seen the php.ini file referenced in that manner. Have you tried running this task via the CLI?

Comment: Hi ceejayoz, how should I have referenced the php.ini? also 
I have never used CLI, mind explaining?

Comment: Usually, you shouldn't need to specify a php.ini location. If you do, it needs to be with the `-c / --php-ini` flag, not just randomly thrown into the line... CLI = command line, just typing your command into your SSH terminal should show you why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a custom php.ini file, you need to use the `-c` or `--php-ini` flag.

```
* * * * *  php --php-ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/automation/cronjob_WDYCI_daily.php
```

In most situations, it's not necessary to specify a particular php.ini file.

Comment: Ok thank you! I was attempting it the way I did on my hosted server before. The way you suggested above worked fine.